# The autoVerifyEmail on PreSignUp trigger does not verify the new user's email

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I trigger the PreSignUp lambda using admin_create_user:

```
        self.cognito.admin_create_user(
            UserPoolId=self.user_pool_id,
            Username=user.username,
            UserAttributes=[
                {
                    'Name': 'name',
                    'Value': user.username
                },
                {
                    'Name': 'email',
                    'Value': user.username
                },
            ],
            MessageAction='SUPPRESS')
```

Which triggers the lambda with this handler:

```
def pre_signup(event, context):

    event['response']['autoConfirmUser'] = True
    event['response']['autoVerifyEmail'] = True
    
    print(f"EVENT: {event}")
    return event
```

And then on Cloudwatch the event is (Sentitive data has been obscured):

```
EVENT: {'version': '1', 'region': 'us-east-X', 'userPoolId': 'us-east-X_XXXXXXXX', 'userName': 'XXXXXXXX-bd2d-4fec-b421-d2c4b89f3274', 'callerContext': {'awsSdkVersion': 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown', 'clientId': 'CLIENT_ID_NOT_APPLICABLE'}, 'triggerSource': 'PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser', 'request': {'userAttributes': {'name': 'XXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXX.com', 'email': 'XXXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXX.com'}, 'validationData': None}, 'response': {'autoConfirmUser': True, 'autoVerifyEmail': True, 'autoVerifyPhone': False}}
```

As you can see, the `autoVerifyEmail` option is set to True, [just as the docs state](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html). Problem is, this thing is broken, it just doesn't work.

Even calling [admin_update_user_attributes](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_update_user_attributes) manually doesn't work.

```
    self.cognito.admin_update_user_attributes(
            UserPoolId=self.user_pool_id,
            Username=user.username,
            UserAttributes=[
                {
                    'Name': 'email_verified',
                    'Value': True
                },
            ]
        )
```

[Even in the AWS forums there are no answers](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=285941). So, is this thing just completely broken or am I doing something wrong? I've even tried setting to a string 'true' just because of the quotes on the docs ('boolean'). I don't know what to do anymore, the user does not get created with a verified email attribute.

Answer (score 1):

For those suffering with this in the future, I've solved it with [admin_update_user_attributes](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_update_user_attributes), the Value MUST BE a string.

```
admin_update_user_attributes_response = self.cognito.admin_update_user_attributes(
        UserPoolId=self.user_pool_id,
        Username=user.username,
        UserAttributes=[
            {
                'Name': 'email_verified',
                'Value': 'true'
            },
        ]
    )
```

Turns out that it was a mistake on my side, I wasn't testing the right endpoint, so I couldn't see the changes of this on cloudwatch. It's hard to test anything related to AWS Cognito, it's not a very user-friendly service.

Comment: How about solving it using the Pre-Signup Lambda Trigger ? Did it work too ?